# Reset drop down and javascript values

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

To see the problem use the link bellow : [example page](http://www.mk18.co.uk/indexTemp.php#order)

Whats happening is if you choose an advert type and choose the amount of issues you want it give you a sub total , vat and total . This is good , but if a user decides they want to select a different advert , the issues box resets to the default message , but the sub total , vat and total boxes dont reset to zero , they hold the amount it would cost to have the new advert with the previous issues . Only after changing the advert again do the sub total ect fileds change to 0.

How would i get them to change straight away?

This is the javascrip statment that is used to get the value of the advert type .

```
if (document.getElementById('advert').value == "item 2 - half page" && document.getElementById('addissues').value == "1 issue")  {adcharge = 320;}
```

This variable 'adcharge' is then shown as the sub total.

Code for drop downs :

```
<select name="advert" id="advert"  onchange="calculate('');"  class="validate[required]">
                          <option value="">Please select the advert required</option>

<option value="Back Cover Display Advert (Full Page)">Back Cover Display Advert (216mm x 154mm)</option>                          
<option value="Inside Front Cover Display Advert">Inside Front Cover Display Advert (Full Page - 136mm x 190mm)</option>
<option value="Inside Front Cover Display AdvertHalf">Inside Front Cover Display Advert (Half Page - 136mm x 93mm)</option>
<option value="Inside Back Cover Display AdvertFull">Inside Back Cover Display Advert (Full Page - 136mm x 190mm)</option>
<option value="Inside Back Cover Display AdvertHalf">Inside Back Cover Display Advert (Half Page - 136mm x 93mm)</option>
<option value="Full Page Display Advert">Full Page Display Advert (136mm x 190mm)</option>
<option value="Half Page Display Advert">Half Page Display Advert (136mm x 93mm)</option>
<option value="Quarter Page Display Advert">Quarter Page Display Advert (66mm x 93mm</option>
<option value="Eighth Page Display Advert">Eighth Page Display Advert (66mm x 44.5mm)</option>

                        </select>
```

The second drop down has some java script that changes the amount of issues based on the advert selected , but is basically the same code as the first box.

If you need me to be more specific , just ask for it in comments.

Comment: your explanation is so hard to understand..post your complete code then try to comment in the code what you want to happen

Comment: @CodeSlayer Iv edited the question , it should be straight forward

Answer (score 0):

did you try this code?

`function valueChange()
{`

```
document.getElementById('subtotal').value=0.0;
document.getElementById('vat').value=0.0;
document.getElementById('total').value=0.0;
document.getElementById('cboIssues').value='Please select the number issues required';
```

`}`

Comment: It dosent work . If i change the onchange bit in the drop down to valueChange(). only the subtotal changes